# Where should i allocate DCB directive in the code

Tags: assembly, arm

I am a newbie to assembly. This code below is supposed to rewrite memory place called size but there is a problem which is that I can reach the address of the `size` but there is not filled with "10" I couldn't figure it out but I think it is about where I allocate DCB in the code. Can anyone help me?

```
       AREA size_era, DATA, READWRITE
size   DCB 10
       AREA the_code, CODE, READONLY
       ALIGN
       THUMB
       EXPORT __main
__main PROC
       LDR R0 ,=size
       MOVS R1, #32
       STRB R1, [R0]
       ENDP
       END
```

The figure below is the relevant screenshot of the code. the address of the `size` is held in R0 and in the relevant location there should be 0x0A but it is not there

[image]

Comment: You forgot to say what the problem is and how you found it out? The code looks fine from a glance. Except for not having an ending of course.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I just edited. Thanks for warning me

Comment: you said the code doesn't have an ending but is END not enough?

Comment: No, that only marks the end of the file. You need to return or exit, depending on your environment. But that has nothing to do with your problem. How do you know the value is not `10`?

Comment: I used Keil uVision  to simulate,  debug and watching the memory

Comment: Can you show a relevant screenshot for example?

Comment: I just added the relevant screenshot

Comment: I don't know what kind of environment Keil uVision provides, but in bare-metal enviroments where you run your program from ROM, it may be necessary for you to write code that copies initialized data to RAM at startup.